# Finding object with multiple unique elements in a list through Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a class A with a list of elements B. Each B furthermore has an object C. What I need to do is to find the instances of A, where there is at least two B instances with different C instances in the list.

```
public class A {
   long id;
   List<B> elements;
}

public class B {
    long id;
    C object;
}

public class C {
    long id;
}
```

I've tried a bunch of different things already, direct comparisons, creating two aliases, DetachedCriteria, and either I get 0 rows, I get every row where there is at least one B, or I get an exception. I never get the one row, that matches what I want.

I'm going mad here, anyone have an idea as to how I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, once I finally give in and post the problem as a question, I find the solution moments later.

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");

DetachedCriteria cCount = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class, "a2");

cCount.createAlias("a2.elements", "elements2");
cCount.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("a2.id", "a.id");
cCount.setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("elements2.object.id");

crit.add(Subqueries.lt(1L, areaCount);

return (List<A>) crit.list();
```